# C# Inputbox cancel button does not work

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, inputbox

I have below code on my browse button.
How can I write code for inputbox cancel button.

```
private void btnbrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String sf_no = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(
        "You are uploading File For SF NO. ", "Information", def, -1, -1);

    ofd.ShowDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    string[] result = ofd.FileNames;

    foreach (string y in result)
    {
        String path = y.Substring(0, y.LastIndexOf("\\"));
        String filename = y.Substring(y.LastIndexOf("\\"));
        string[] row = new string[] { sf_no,path, filename };
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()` and `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()` methods instead of the `y.SubString()` calls to make it safer.

Comment: I have written but it gives error

Comment: Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName();
 filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName();
            string[] row = new string[] { sf_no, path, filename };
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);'

Comment: @Shweta Of course it won't work, use GetDirectoryName(y) and GetFileName(y). Press F1 on GetDirectoryName and GetFileName and it will explain to you everything. In fact, your whole question would be answered had you just press F1 on InputBox

Comment: Ya done that its working. thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Cancellation of InputBox, the return value is an empty string, so your code would be

```
if (sf_no!="")
{
//ok stuff here, including the showdialog logic as shown below
}
{
//cancel stuff here
}
```

Since `ofd.ShowDialog` can also be cancelled your code should be :

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
{ 
//do stuff on OK button 
}
else 
{
//do stuff on Cancel button
}
```

Either call `ofd.Multiselect = true;` *before* calling ShowDialog() or set it on Properties box if you'll always have Multiselect anyway.

Thus, your new code are now :

```
private void btnbrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       String sf_no = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("You are uploading File For SF NO. ", "Information", def, -1, -1);

       if (sf_no!="") //we got the sf_no
       {
           ofd.Multiselect = true;
           if (ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)//user select file(s)
           {

                string[] result = ofd.FileNames;          

                foreach (string y in result)
                {

                  String path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(y);
                  String filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(y);
                  string[] row = new string[] { sf_no,path, filename };
                  dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
                 }
           }
           else
           {
           //handle what happen if user click cancel while selecting file  
           }
       }
       else
       {
       //handle what happen if user click cancel while entering SF NO
       }





    }
```

Comment: can you  please giveme idea which code(from my queation) i need to add in if else condition

Comment: Edited my answer to show what your new code should be